# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: python, opencv, vagrant

I am using Data science toolbox running ubuntu 14.04 through vagrant in windows.
I installed OpenCV and tried a very simple python code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

img = cv2.imread('image1.jpg' , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
cv2.imshow('image' , img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllwindows()
```

When i run this code i get an error -

```
(image:1267): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I have searched on internet but not able to find a solution working for me.

I have tried -

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY=:0
```

and many more.
I have also tried xhost +localhost but this gives another error

```
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

Anyone know a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward the display to your host, in your Vagrantfile, add the following lines

```
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
```

You will need a X-server running on your windows machine (I personally use [Quartz](http://www.xquartz.org/) on my mac, you would need to get an equivalent for windows, like [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/xmingnotes/))  and then when you `vagrant up` to boot your VM, when you will run an X-program it will pop-up on your host.