# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0 --- Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.2

I have just installed OpenCV 3.2.0 on an amazon EC2 instance (ubuntu 14.04). When I try to run any of the sample programs I get the error  `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0`
Answers to similar questions online didn't work for me. I've tried 
`export DISPLAY=:0.0`
`export DISPLAY=:0`
and I tried `xhost +localhost` and received `xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"`

This post describes the exact same problems as me, but I'm not using Vagrant, so there is no "Vagrantfile" and I don't know what the equivalent would be in an EC2 instance.
[Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919821/gtk-warning-cannot-open-display)

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Can you tell me if your using ssh to get in? Did you run xhost+ before the ssh command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using ssh to Ubuntu 16.04.2 server. I can do the following:

```
xhost +
ssh -Y -i .ssh/my.pem ubuntu@ecxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
sudo apt install x11-apps
xclock
```

This starts the xclock applet on my local display. Note the xhost + before I ssh and the -Y flag on the ssh command. I'm using xclock to test which I installed from x11-apps. You should be able to start OpenCV in a similar way.

Comment: I'm using Putty to get onto the instance, and if I try to run `xhost +` i just get the error `xhost:  unable to open display ""`. I'm not sure how it would be possible to run xhost + before puttying in

Comment: I don't really understand why this was put on hold but thanks for answering

Comment: Try using cygwin or with PUTTY try http://www.computers-it.com/general/general_x11_forwarding.php

Comment: yes i had to set up x11 forwarding. Before you commented I saw this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRsma2vkEQE
which helped me a lot. Thanks!